# Switch between mobile and full site

Tags: php, html, mobile

All my full site pages are under folder `public_html`, which contains `index.php` and folder `m` which contains all the mobile site pages. `index.php` is like this:

```
<?php
  if (...mobile client) {
    header('Location: m/');
  } else {
    include 'front.html.php';
  }
?>
```

There is also an `index.php` in `m`, simply `include 'front.html'.

This script can detect user's client and direct to full site and mobile site automatically.

But now I want a link on the mobile site to switch to full site. If it is like `<a href="../front.html.php">switch to full site</a>`, there will be `front.html.php` in the address bar, and I don't want this. However, if it is like `<a href="../">switch to full site</a>`, it will detect again and back to mobile site.

How to deal with that?

Comment: is just the design that differs between the two versions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting a cookie.

```
  setcookie("forceClient", "full", time()+3600);
```

Then from that php script, redirect to the home page.

In your index.php, check the cookie:

```
if($_COOKIE["forceClient"] == "full"){
  //logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a session variable 
like

```
$_SESSION['viewer_type'] = "Mobile";
```

or

```
$_SESSION['viewer_type'] = "Regulare";
```

and then define a new variable call it base_url and save it in the session also 
and do this

```
if($_SESSION['viewer_type'] == 'Mobile'):
     $_SESSION['base_url'] = "http://www.m.site.com/";
else:
     $_SESSION['base_url'] = "http://www.site.com/"; 
endif;
```

the link now will be

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['base_url'] ?>front.html.php">Test</a>
```

You need to set the session variable each time the view changed from mobile to regular or visa versa

Comment: But `$_SESSION['base_url']` in the link is the mobile link, right?

Comment: no both 
when you change your view the value of the base_url will change based on your directories

Comment: Yes. I want the link on the mobile page, and link to the full page.

Comment: this will do it for you if the pages have the same name on different folders

Comment: But when click the link, `....front.html.php` will still appear in the url. Thus I need to link to the folder instead of the page.

Comment: use ajax and javscript or .htacdss if you don't want the link to show up