# php session to check if you already redirected the user

Tags: php, session, redirect

I do not have a database.

My website will use a php class (`mobiledetect.php`) to find the user agent and type of browser, whereby a certain .css file is parsed.  If the user prefers to view the full css site, how can I create a php session so as not to redirect the user again.  So, only to ask the first php class once?

I am new to php.

Comment: Session? Redirect? it's confused, can you post AND SHOW your point in your code?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch between mobile and full site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461301/switch-between-mobile-and-full-site)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I see two options that you have -- one is to just store the information locally (in the PHP session), the other is to store the user preferences in a cookie.

If you could actually show us your `mobiledetect.php` code, it would probably be easier to help you with actual code.